# Mallet - SimpleTagger Main class not found

Tags: java, mallet

I downloaded and installed the latest version of Mallet. I build it with success but when I try to run SimpleTagger :

java -cp mallet-deps.jar cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --train true --model-file nouncrf  sample

or

java -cp "/mallet/class:/lib/mallet-deps.jar" cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --train true --model-file nouncrf  sample

I checked the path to the class it is correct and the path to the .jar

But every time I have the same error : main class cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger not found !!!

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used that library, but from taking a glance at the downloadable zip, it seems you should add `dist/mallet.jar` and `dist/mallet-deps.jar` to your classpath.

Something like this (adapt the root-directory as necessary):

```
java -cp "mallet/dist/mallet-deps.jar:mallet/dist/mallet.jar" cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --train true --model-file nouncrf sample
```

Be aware that on a Windows-System the classpath-separator is a ";" while on Linux (and MacOS) it is ":".

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response !!!
It works !
I use : java -cp mallet-deps.jar:mallet.jar cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --train true --model-file nouncrf sample